# put a value to the next item with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new with jquery.
I'm changing the value of an input text and I need to change the value of the next input text, so my code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

$('[type=text]').change(function() {

        $(this).next('input').val("newvalue");
    });

});
```

But nothing... !

---

*EDIT: Posting HTML from comment below*

```
<form method="post" action="/volume/create"> 
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <th><label for="volume_h1">H1</label></th> 
            <td><input type="text" id="volume_h1" name="volume[h1]"></td> 
        </tr> 
        <!-- .............. to volume_h24 -->
        <tr> 
            <th><label for="volume_h24">H24</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="volume_h24" name="volume[h24]"></td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
</form>
```

Comment: Is the input directly next to the input the handler is attached to? If not, you'll need `nextAll()`

Comment: You should also post relevant html.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Based on the updated information you provided, this should work:

```
$('input[type=text]').change(function() {
    var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find('input:text');
    var nextIndex = inputs.index( this ) + 1;
    inputs.slice( nextIndex ).val( this.value );
});
```

---

**Original solution:**

Hard to tell without seeing your markup, but I'm guessing you have some element in between the two.

```
$('input[type=text]').change(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('input:first').val("newvalue");
});
```

Can't give much more of an answer without seeing your HTML.

Note that I changed the selector from `'[type=text]'` to `'input[type=text]'`, which will be more efficient.

Comment: in fact i got a form with 20 input text and i want to propagate value of an input to all the next item under this one, i try with this : $(this).nextall("input:text").attr('value',"newvalue"); and $(this).next("input:text").val("newvalue"); but noting ???

Comment: @cedosh: The proper method of selecting the inputs you want depends *entirely* on your HTML markup. Without that, we're just guessing.

Comment: @cedosh: I updated my answer to do what I *think* you want. There may be a better way, but hard to tell without seeing your HTML.

Comment: nothing more with this but it is excatelly what i want !    my html code :   <form method="post" action="/volume/create">
  <table>
<tr>
  <th><label for="volume_h1">H1</label></th>
  <td><input type="text" id="volume_h1" name="volume[h1]"></td>
</tr>

..............to volume_h24

<tr>
  <th><label for="volume_h24">H24</label></th>
  <td><input type="text" id="volume_h24" name="volume[h24]"></td>
</tr>
  </table>
</form>

Comment: @codethis: Your answer will only work if they are siblings. In the HTML that @cedosh posted, they're not siblings.

Answer (score 0):

This will change all of them down the line:

```
$("input:text").change(function() {
    var v = $(this).next("input:text");
    v.val($(this).val());
    v.trigger('change');
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uDgnt/

Comment: This seems more like a comment. In any case, why would that happen? `.next()` only selects 1 element.

Comment: it doesn't.  I tested it and was curious.  I thought it would have because the change event is getting added to every textbox, not just one.  the change event doesn't fire on the second textbox though

Comment: ok, I see you deleted that from your answer. Anyway, I think I see what you meant. Like if there were several inputs as direct siblings, the change in one would trigger the change handler in the next, and so on. Doesn't seem to be the case. That would require `$(this).next().val('tester').change();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try By :

```
$(this).attr('value',"newvalue");
```

Comment: i try this but nothing again...     $(this).next("input:text").attr('value',"newvalue");

Comment: if it is adjacent then use only$(this).next().attr('value',"newvalue");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, your solutions seemed to be good but i didn't suceed with the `next()` function.

Finally i did this :

```
$('input[type=text]').change(function() {
       //get all the input text of the form
    var yourFormFields = $('#newform').find(':input[type=text]');
      // the index of my changed input
    $index = yourFormFields.index( this );
     //the value i entered
    $mavalue = $(this).val();

       $.each( yourFormFields, function(i, n){
    if(i>$index)
    {yourFormFields.eq(i).val($mavalue);}
         });

});
```